# What's the easiest/proper way to wire Spring beans outside a webapp?

Tags: java, spring

I am developing an non-web application and I would like to set up Spring in it. I would like to have minimal configuration that supports auto-wiring. What's the proper way to do this? Do I need to implement my own `ApplicationContext` loading mechanism, or is there something better I could do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring provides an IoC container in the form of an `ApplicationContext`. However, you need to implement your own mechanism for creating the container. But that can be pretty simple

```
public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = ...// whichever flavor you want
        // maybe start some threads, possibly managed by the IoC container
    }
}
```

The container itself can either use XML configuration or a programatic one. Read the official documentation on how to do either, [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html).

Comment: I was frankly hoping for a more intelligent way of doing it. When it's a webapp, Spring initializes all the beans for you as soon as the application starts loading in the container. The classes which sub-class ApplicationContext are great, but my problem is that I don't want to have to lookup beans through my code, but rather -- have some class that scans through my package and autowires things for me. Is this at all possible?

Comment: @carlspring That's what the `ApplicationContext` does internally. It can autowire everything you tell it to. You almost don't need to make any `getBean()` calls. Read the 5th chapter of the documentation I've linked.

Comment: Right, I see what you mean. Thanks! :)